# How do I install typescript definitions for Electron?

Tags: typescript, electron

I have two problems:

- Which definitions should I install? `typings search electron` returns quite a few results.
- How do I install them? `typings install dt~github-electron --global --save` gives me an error:

  > Attempted to compile "github-electron" as an external module, but it
  >   looks like a global module. You'll need to enable the global option to
  >   continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **source** needs to be set to **dt** and it seems to work just fine.

```
$ typings install github-electron --source dt --global
```

Comment: Ah, my problem was different – I had run it through `npm run typings install...` so the --global option was interpreted by npm instead of typings. My original command worked after I added -- before the typings options.

Comment: glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: I just had the same problem as @AlexGrönholm. I had `typings` installed as local, meaning that the `--global` option was interpreted by the `npm run typings ...` command. Running `npm install typings --global` and then the `typings install ... --global` worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using TypeScript version 2.0 + you can use npm to get that by executing following line

```
npm install --save @types/electron
```

Here is a quick reference from typescript documentation

> http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html

if you are using typescript version lower than 2 either you can use typing which other peoples already helped regard that

Comment: Yes, this has recently gotten much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a different typing name :

```
typings install electron/github-electron --source dt --save --global
```